# Xamarin.Android Package Releasing issue?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk, release

I am having issue in releasing my xamarin.android app.
I have tried to install my released apk file in 3 android devices (one 6.0.1 android version device - two 7.0 android version devices) and faced different issues:

- On 1st device, received "app not installed" error on clicking install button.
- On 2nd device, app doesn't show install option.
- On 3rd device, sometimes app gets install and sometimes receives "app not installed" error.

  Steps i followed:
- Archived App bundle in release mode.
- Distributed using Ad-Hoc.
- and following are App properties (Screenshots are attached)

Thanks in advance!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31sN1.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D3H7.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZKCD.png) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPK5i.png) [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLEUA.png) [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGh03.png)

Comment: Are all of your code dependencies OK to be compiled with the latest SDK for your target  version?

Comment: some packages are not latest but app works fine in debug mode